# Embedding CW-complexes into infinite-dimensional topological vector spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, dimension-theory, cw-complexes, embeddings

Sometimes it is desirable to embed CW-complexes into real vector spaces, to use a simple linear algebra to work with them. Result on embedding into Euclidean spaces are well known, check Hatcher‘s Algebraic Topology for example. But since I learned about this result I was wondering if there are similar results for ‘larger’ vector spaces.

It is well known result that a locally-finite finite-dimensional CW-complex $(X,\mathcal{E},\varphi)$ such that $\lvert\mathcal{E}\rvert\le \aleph_0$ can be homeomorphically embedded into space $\mathbb{R}^{1+2n}$, where $n$ is the dimension of the complex. See for the detailed proof [CW-complexes and Euclidean spaces](https://epub.ub.uni-muenchen.de/4524/1/4524.pdf) by Rudolf Fritsch and Renzo Piccinini. It seems that in the case of infinite-dimensional complexes it still must be possible to embed it into space $\mathbb{R}^{\oplus \mathbb{N}}$ by considering a direct limit of embeddings of skeleta $X_n \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{k(n)}$  with the final topology (but I may be wrong here).

Moreover, it seems that local-finiteness is required for ensuring local compactness of the embedding. So,  the embeddings of skeleta $X_n \hookrightarrow V_n$ may still exist if $V_n$ are infinite-dimensional topological vector spaces, even if $X$ is not locally finite. Thus, $X$ must have embedding into a direct limit $\varinjlim V_n$, which is hopefully an LF-space. the It also may be the case, but I'm not so sure, that the condition $\lvert\mathcal{E}\rvert\le \aleph_0$ can also be relaxed if one considers spaces which are not second-countable. So, there still may exist CW-complexes which are embeddable into such vector space, but are not embeddable into any Euclidean space for the obvious reasons.

So, the idea is to embed CW-complexes, which are not normally embeddable into euclidean spaces into some ‘very large’ space, which still has vector space structure. So my question:

Is there any obvious reasons why this approach is deemed to fail? Is there any known results on embedding CW-complexes into infinite dimensional spaces? Is there any simple conditions which may prevent a CW-complex from being embeddable into any vector space? (For example not being $T_3$-regular, but I don't know such examples.) Are there any conditions for embeddability of a CW-complex into an arbitrary vector space, but not yet a Euclidean space?

The most dull result possible here is something like: Embedding in topological vector space exists iff embedding in Euclidean space exists. But this result seems to be too strong and strict.

I will be grateful for any pieces of information.

Comment: To me there's perhaps the most functional example: take a space that is naturally a Hilbert manifold of some sort, that you know has the homotopy-type of a countable CW complex.  For example, the diffeomorphism group of a compact manifold.   Or the space of embeddings of one manifold into another, or say an iterated loop space of a manifold, etc.

Comment: Every CW complex is Tychonoff, and hence it embeds into a (possibly uncountable) product of compact intervals. What kind of vector space would like to embed into? Every Tychonoff space $X$  (such as the product of intervals, or any CW complex) embeds into the free topological vector space over $X$, see e.g. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1604.04005.pdf.

Comment: @Igor thanks for your answer. I didn't knew about free topological vector spaces. I plan to read this paper now.

Comment: In fact every Tychonoff space embeds as a closed, linearly independent subset of a locally convex TVS (this is [Arens-Eells](https://msp.org/pjm/1956/6-3/pjm-v6-n3-p01-s.pdf)).

Answer (score 2):

This is a comment but it will be too long—hence the use of answer format.  There is a standard procedure to embed the objects of suitable manifold type categories into complete locally convex spaces in a canonical way.  The basic idea is to consider the free vector space over the object and provide it with the finest l.c. structure such that the natural embedding of the original object therein has a suitable structural property.  One then  completes this l.c.s.  This rather vague description will become clearer if we consider what is perhaps the simplest case—that of the category of topological spaces, more precisely completely regular ones (otherwise there is no hope of embedding in a l.c.s.).   We give the free vector space $\Lambda(X)$ over such a space the finest l.c.s. topology such that the corresponding embedding of $X$ into $\Lambda(X)$ is continuous and then take the completion. There are many examples which can be dealt with similarly—most notably categories of uniform spaces,  smooth manifolds, complex manifolds, piecewise linear manifolds.  The essential element is that there is a clear notion of what it means for a function on an object of the category with values in  a l.c.s. to have the correct structural property (in the above cases, continuity, uniform continuity, smoothness, partial linearity).  These l.c.s.’s then have a suitable universal property which characterises them uniquely and in the above examples, they have natural interpretations as spaces of measures or distributions.

I have never speculated on whether a suitable version of this construction would work in your situatiion—hence the tentative nature of this contribution as a comment rather than answer—but it might be worth a try.

Comment: Perhaps some references would be nice?

Comment: So, it it is possible to build space of regular measures and distributions over a CW-complex and then embed it as  delta-measure for example. This is an interesting idea.

Comment: @Sam Sanders  This has been studied extensively over the last 80 years, mostly in the  former S.U. and Czechoslovakia.  The first result I am aware of is for the embedding of a completely regular space into a locally convex space  due to A. Markoff (1941). Further relevant authors are Katétov, Tomášek and John (for the smooth case).  It is closely related to work of  Graev and Raikov on free topological groups.  It will be easier for you to check these authors on MR than for me to dig out precise references.  One often ascribes Markoff's result to Arens and Eells but that came later (1956).

Comment: Thanks for the references!